# import logical relation between components In Micorosoft visio Pro

Tags: diagram, visio

I would like to use an excel as input to construct a diagram. This example shows the idea:

### input.xls

```
step    outputs
start   step1
step1   step2,step3
step2   step2
step3   end
end
```

### Expected output in Visio Pro:

[image]

Comment: please let me know if you know any tool that can do this task.

Answer (score 1):

May be Data Visualizer can help ?
[Create a Data Visualizer diagram](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-Data-Visualizer-diagram-17211b46-d144-4ca2-9ea7-b0f48f0ae0a6)
[Automatically create process diagrams in Visio from Excel data](https://blogs.office.com/en-us/2017/05/01/automatically-create-process-diagrams-in-visio-from-excel-data/)

Comment: and also http://visualsignals.typepad.co.uk/vislog/2017/06/visio-data-visualizer-part-1-the-process.html

Comment: Sorry John, i forget added hyperlink to your article ! And David J Parker article  - https://blog.bvisual.net/2017/05/18/data-visualizer-for-visio-pro-for-office-365-part-1/

Comment: thanks for answer and comments. Seems like it only works with office365 and not with Visio Pro 2016 :-(

Comment: You are right, only for Visio Pro for Office 365 Version 1703 (Build 7967.2139). Check this article  https://support.office.com/en-us/article/What-s-new-in-Visio-2016-798f4f39-2833-486b-9ae9-55162672102e?ad=IN&rs=en-IN&ui=en-US (See March 2017 updates)